# Release ViewControllers Associated with UITabBarController with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, dealloc

I am working in application where i have below kind of structure

```
-UINavigationController (MAIN NAVIGATION CONTROLLER)
--UIViewController
---UITabBarController
     -- UINavigationController1
     ---- UITableViewController1

     -- UINavigationController2
     ---- UITableViewController2

     -- UIViewController ( Logout Button is in this Controller )
```

Now I am calling below method to Logout user to First ViewController

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Here self.navigationController = (MAIN NAVIGATION CONTROLLER)

but this code does not work, It does not deinit below controllers.

```
-- UINavigationController1
---- UITableViewController1

-- UINavigationController2
---- UITableViewController2
```

I am using ARC so I can not call release method for all controllers so How can I achieve this.

**UPDATE**

Here is my push code:

```
//Property Declare in AppDelegate
@property (nonatomic,weak) UITabBarController *tabBarControllerRef;

// Below code Written in RootViewController of (MAIN NAVIGATION CONTROLLER)
-(void)moveToContentScreen { 
AppDelegate *delegateRef = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
delegateRef.tabBarControllerRef = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbarReference"];
if (delegateRef.tabBarControllerRef) {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:delegateRef.tabBarControllerRef animated:YES];
}
}
```

Comment: What about the tab controller? Does it `deinit`? If not, you make have a reference cycle.

Answer (score 0):

What is almost certainly happening here is that you have a strong reference cycle; two (or more) objects each both holding strong references to the other(s) in a cycle so that none of them can be deleted. For instance, does the UITabBarController have a strong reference to its enclosing view? If so, make at least one of the references weak to break the cycle.

If it's not apparent by review what objects might be cyclically referencing each other, you can use Instruments to attempt to find them; there is [an excellent tutorial here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/97886/instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started), the "Strong Reference Cycles" section discussing pretty much exactly this kind of problem.

Comment: How can I make uitabbarcontroller reference weak as I push from MainNavigationController

Comment: When you push it, are you assigning it at that point to a property? They're strong by default, so that property declaration needs to be weak. Show us the code you use to push the controllers onto `self.navigationController` then we could probably see what's wrong.

Comment: Hmmm. Perhaps `UITableViewController1` and `UITableViewController2` reference each other? Or does some other object hold references to them?

Comment: nope... it's connected with navigationcontroller and navigationcontroller connected to uitabbarcontroller

Comment: in UITableViewController1 I have some methods working in background is that stopping view controller to dealloc?

Comment: Ah, yes. If you're using anything asynchronous, then you need to be aware of the capture rules. Any completion handler in a view controller that calls a method or property on "self" creates a strong reference to it. If anything has a strong reference to that completion handler, boom we have a cycle. To get rid of that we do what is known as the "strong weak dance". [Here is a concise explanation](https://dhoerl.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/i-finally-figured-out-weakself-and-strongself/).

Answer (score 0):

How does the root `UIViewController` present the `UITabBarController`? Child/parent? If so, it looks like the first `UIViewController` view controller still holds a reference to the `UITabBarController`. From your diagram, it looks like the initial `UINavigationController` only has one pushed `UIViewController`, the root one.

Comment: Is there a need to have a property for the `UITabBarController`? Using public properties on `UIApplicationDelegate` for global access is bad practice. Try just creating the `UITabBarController` locally and pushing it.

Comment: UITabBarController *controllerRef = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbarReference"];
     if (controllerRef) {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controllerRef animated:YES];
     }